# Ubuntu 18.04 can't pair bluetooth devices

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez

I just got my new linux computer today, and everything is working fine excepts the bluetooth.
I can find bluetooth devices, but when I try to pair a device nothing happens. And when I checked the syslog for bluetooth errors. I got this error:

```
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_5C_13_02_39_51 failed: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected: Authentication Rejected
```

And when I got the computer the bluetooth did work, then I updated the kernel to 5.4.0-53 and then it stopped working.

I have tried to look around for information, but can't find anything related. Hopefully someone in here can help me out with this :)

Edit:output from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and output from the command dmesg | grep -i blue:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: request failed to create LE connection: status 0x0c
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 that is done now

Comment: OK, then add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: That is also added now

Comment: Hm, try to boot with the previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: I know it was working in some 4. kernel. But I will try to boot to the previous kernel thru the grub. Just need to look up how :P

Comment: @Pilot6 so I ahve now tried to boot in other kernel now without any progress. And I have still no idea what todo here